# I have set the Project Interpreter to `python 3.5.2`, but seems the my project still use `python 2.7`

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I have set the Project Interpreter to `python 3.5.2`, pay attention there are two packages only `python 3.5.2` have:

[image]

but seems the my project still use `python 2.7`, when I runserver:

[image]

the traceback:

```
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.2-py2.7.egg/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.2-py2.7.egg/django/apps/config.py", line 94, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named rest_auth
```

---

**EDIT**

My project Run/Debug Configuration is `3.5.2` too.

[image]

Comment: Change the configuration https://imgur.com/UFuAsY6

Comment: @yklsga How to do with that?

Comment: this might help https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html

Comment: @yklsga See my edit.

Comment: You are launching your application directly from terminal but not clicking "Run" button. Pycharm is Pycharm and terminal is terminal, they are different. Your configuration will only work if you launch using Pycharm.

Comment: @Sraw Yes, you right! thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Sraw mentioned in the comment you are launching your application directly from terminal but not clicking "Run" button.

If you want to launching django from pycharm follow this tutorial
(This feature is supported in the Professional edition only.)
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/step-4-creating-and-running-your-first-django-project.html

**The best solution is using the virtual environment with or without pycharm**

with pycharm 
Configuring Python virtual environment in pycharm
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html

without pycharm
http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/#lower-level-virtualenv